# css for 2 inc/dec buttons by an input that reposition properly when resizing screen

Tags: html, css

I want to display an input box in html and 2 small buttons to the right, one on top of each other. Something like this

[https://jsfiddle.net/danaya/yw94f0Lt/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/danaya/yw94f0Lt/1/)

The html code is simple

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="name">product</div>
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text" size="3" value="1">
    <div class="inc">+</div>
    <div class="dec">-</div>
  </div>
  <div class="price">2.99</div>
</div>
```

And this is the css

```
.list {
  display: flex;
}

.name,
.input,
.price {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.name {
  width: 50%;
}

.input,
.price {
  text-align: right;
  width: 25%;
}

.input {
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
}

input {
  line-height: 25px;
}

.inc,
.dec {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  background-color: #999;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.inc {
  top: 11px;
  left: 40px;
}

.dec {
  top: 25px;
  left: 40px;
}
```

As it is right now, when I resize the window, the div.input is resized and so the buttons, being related to the input, lose their position by the input element.

I need to keep the flex display in the .list element, but other than that I can change anything. I also need the buttons to not increase the width of the div.input element, that's why I'm using the position:relative.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I think you can use `position: absolute;` and give `div.input` an appropriate `padding-right` instead?

Comment: @david, maybe it would be better if you used `type="number"` as it comes with two 'buttons' by default. The buttons are up and down arrows instead of plus and minus though.

Comment: Thanks @Mers, I know, but I can't use it in this case, it's a requirement

Comment: You're welcome, @david. I'd like to help you but I cannot reproduce your issue with your current code. You said that the `div.input` resizes when you resize the browser window; however, with current code you posted, this does happen on my end. When I resize the browser window, your element `input` doesn't get resized --it stays the same size.

Comment: You're right, @Mers, this was not properly set. I just updated the jsfiddle, now if you resize the screen you will see that the column on the right pushes or pulls the buttons and everything is a mess.
I'm working in my css skills, so maybe I'm doing this totally the wrong way...

Comment: Cool, thanks @david. Check the answer below. Hopefully it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.name,
.price {
padding: 0 10px;
}

.input, input {
  box-sizing: border-box; /*to set the equal height to bot .input and input*/
  height: 31px; /*13 + 13 (buttons) + 5 (paddings for buttons) = 31px */
 
}
.input {
  position: relative;
  /*width: 25%; Use this if you want to increate the width of your div.input*/
}
input {
  padding-right: 15px; /* 15px set so that input characters do not go underneath the + and - buttons */
  width: 100%; /* set 100% so that input will take 100% width of its parent size */
}

.inc,
.dec {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  background-color: #999;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.inc {
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
}

.dec {
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="name">product</div>
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text" size="3" value="1">
    <span class="inc">+</span>
    <span class="dec">-</span>
  </div>
  <div class="price">2.99</div>
</div>
```